# Is it possible to change the name of duplicated entry using PHP?

Tags: php

Column name called `title (nvarchar)`, if i add a name **eg:(john)** then the next time i enter the same name it must show `john (1)`, then `john (2)` etc..

> **Is it possible to insert the value like that without any javascript?**

I tried something like this,

```html
$sqll="select max(seq) as mx from poll_portal";
$qryl = DB_query($sqll,$db);
if ($resl = DB_fetch_array($qryl)) {
  if ($resl['mx'] != NULL and $resl['mx'] > 0 ){
    $newidl = $resl['mx'] + 1;
  } else {
    $newidl=1;
  }
}
      
$sqlp="select count('title') as tp from poll_portal where title='".$_POST['title']."'";
$resultp=DB_query($sqlp,$db);
$rowp = DB_fetch_array($resultp);
if($rowp['tp']==1) {
  $title=$_POST['title']."(".$newidl.")";
} else { 
  $title=$_POST['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can `if($rowp['tp']==1)` to `if($rowp['tp'] > 0)`

And `$title=$_POST['title']."(".$newidl.")";` to `$title = $_POST['title']."(".$rowp['tp'] + 1.")";`

```
$sqlp = "select count('title') as tp from poll_portal where title='".$_POST['title']."'";
$resultp = DB_query($sqlp,$db);
$rowp = DB_fetch_array($resultp);
if ($rowp['tp'] > 0) {
    $title = $_POST['title']."(".$rowp['tp'] + 1.")";
} else {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
}
```

So on first entry of name `John` save as `John` itself & next time save as `John(2)`. If you do not need to start duplicates from `2` avoid `+1`.